# Simplifying type annotations

Tags: scala, types

I've created a pimp method, `collate`, that's usable from any `Traversable` or any type that can be coerced to a traversable as per the following example:

```
val ints = List(0,9,4,5,-3,-5,6,5,-2,1,0,6,-3,-2)
val results = ints collate {
  case i: Int if(i < 0) => i.floatValue
} andThen {
  case i: Int if(i>5) => i.toString
} andThen {
  case i: Int if(i==0) => i
} toTuple

/*
results: (List[Float], List[java.lang.String], List[Int], List[Int]) =
(List(-3.0, -5.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0),List(9, 6, 6),List(0, 0),List(4, 5, 5, 1))
*/
```

Think of it as the unholy spawn of a union 'twixt `collect` and `partition`, if you will...

It's defined like this:

```
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

class Collatable[Repr <% Traversable[T], T](xs: Repr) {

  // Results handling stuff, bit like a poor-man's HList, feel free to skip...

  trait Results {
    def remainder: Repr

    type Append[That] <: Results
    def append[That](tup: (That, Repr)): Append[That]

    def andThen[R, That](pf: PartialFunction[T, R])
    (implicit
      matchesBuilder: CanBuildFrom[Repr, R, That],
      remainderBuilder: CanBuildFrom[Repr, T, Repr]
    ) = {
      val more = (new Collatable[Repr,T](remainder)).collateOne[R,That](pf)
      append(more)
    }
  }

  case class Results9[M1,M2,M3,M4,M5,M6,M7,M8,M9](
    m1: M1, m2: M2, m3: M3, m4: M4, m5: M5, m6: M6, m7: M7, m8: M8, m9: M9,
    remainder: Repr)
  extends Results {
    implicit def toTuple = (m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9, remainder)
    def append[That](tup: (That, Repr)) = error("too many")
  }

  // ... skip a bit, still in results logic ...

  case class Results2[M1,M2](
    m1: M1, m2: M2, remainder: Repr)
  extends Results {
    implicit def toTuple = (m1, m2, remainder)
    type Append[That] = Results3[M1,M2,That]
    def append[That](tup: (That, Repr)) = Results3(m1, m2, tup._1, tup._2)
  }

  case class Results1[M1](matches: M1, remainder: Repr) extends Results {
    implicit def toTuple = (matches, remainder)

    type Append[That] = Results2[M1, That]
    def append[That](tup: (That, Repr)) = Results2(matches, tup._1, tup._2)
  }

  // and now... Our feature presentation!

  def collateOne[R, That](pf: PartialFunction[T, R])
  (implicit
    matchesBuilder: CanBuildFrom[Repr, R, That],
    remainderBuilder: CanBuildFrom[Repr, T, Repr]
  ) = {
    val matches = matchesBuilder(xs)
    val remainder = remainderBuilder(xs)
    for (x <- xs) if (pf.isDefinedAt(x)) matches += pf(x) else remainder += x
    (matches.result, remainder.result)
  }

  def collate[R, That](pf: PartialFunction[T, R])
  (implicit
    matchesBuilder: CanBuildFrom[Repr, R, That],
    remainderBuilder: CanBuildFrom[Repr, T, Repr]
  ): Results1[That]  = {
    val tup = collateOne[R,That](pf)
    Results1(tup._1, tup._2)
  }
}

object Collatable {
  def apply[Repr, T](xs: Repr)(implicit witness: Repr => Traversable[T]) = {
    new Collatable[Repr, T](xs)
  }
}

implicit def traversableIsCollatable[CC[X] <: Traversable[X], A](xs: CC[A]) =
  Collatable[CC[A], A](xs)
implicit def stringIsCollatable(xs: String) =
  Collatable[String, Char](xs)
```

Conceptually, it's not all that daunting once you understand how `CanBuildFrom` works, but I'm finding that it's it's overwhelmed by boilerplate - especially with the implicits.

I know that I could simplify the ResultX logic a great deal by using an HList, and that's something I probably will do, so that piece of code doesn't especially worry me.

I also know that I could make my life *significantly* easier if I was able to constrain `Repr` as a subtype of `Traversable`.  But I refuse do that, because then it couldn't be used against Strings.  By the same token, I'd also like to avoid forcing the partial functions to return a subtype of T - although this is less of a concern as I could always break my logic into distinct collate and map operations.

More concerning is `CanBuildFrom[Repr, T, Repr]`, which I seem to keep repeating, and which obscures the important stuff from my method signatures.  This is something I feel sure can be defined just once at the class level, but I haven't yet found a way to make it work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd rename `andThen` to `orElse`.

Comment: By the way, I loved this method.

Comment: @Daniel - I'll take the name under advisement, though I'm not convinced that `orElse` gives the right sense of chaining the operations together.  My preference would be `then`, which is already taken as a keyword, and I'm still undecided about `+` .

Comment: @Daniel - Glad you liked it, you don't want to know how many variations I went through when I upgraded the thing to work on Strings as well as traversables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define types:

```
class Collatable[Repr <% Traversable[T], T](xs: Repr) {

  // Results handling stuff, bit like a poor-man's HList, feel free to skip...

  type With[-Elem] = CanBuildFrom[Repr, Elem, Repr]
  type CanBuild[-Elem, +To] = CanBuildFrom[Repr, Elem, To]

  trait Results {
    def remainder: Repr

    type Append[That] <: Results
    def append[That](tup: (That, Repr)): Append[That]

    def andThen[R, That](pf: PartialFunction[T, R])
    (implicit
      matchesBuilder: CanBuild[R, That],
      remainderBuilder: With[T]
    ) = {
      val more = (new Collatable[Repr,T](remainder)).collateOne[R,That](pf)
      append(more)
    }
  }

  def collateOne[R, That](pf: PartialFunction[T, R])
  (implicit
    matchesBuilder: CanBuild[R, That],
    remainderBuilder: With[T]
  ) = { 
    val matches = matchesBuilder(xs)
    val remainder = remainderBuilder(xs)
    for (x <- xs) if (pf.isDefinedAt(x)) matches += pf(x) else remainder += x
    (matches.result, remainder.result)
  }   
}
```

On the other hand, I just noticed that the whole `Collatable` is parameterized on `Repr` and `T`, so why don't you get the implicit `remainderBuilder` at that level? **Edit** Because `T` has not been inferred yet. For now, I don't know how to get rid of the extra implicits.

Comment: I tried pushing the builder up to the class level and moving the view bound into a dedicated implicit, as per your second example. Oddly, it just wasn't resolving the builder when I did that.  Then again... I notice that you specified `remainderBuilder` before `ev` - the opposite order to my trials.  Could it really be that simple?

Comment: Of course, it may just be the case that I discovered a bug in the compiler which stops it working as it should! This is certainly close enough to the bleeding edge of the type system to make that possible...

Comment: Type aliasing works, and certainly cleans up the code a bit, but parameter ordering makes no difference. If I pull that builder up to the class scope then the thing compiles, but implicit resolution fails when trying to use it. Defining the builder by using `implicitly[ ]` within the class has the same problem.  Still stumped, I'm going to see if it makes any difference now by compiling instead of using the REPL.

Comment: @Kevin what if you do `implicit val rB = remainderBuilder` at the start of the class?

Comment: I can't see that helping, the implicit resolution fails at class creation time. But I'm willing to try anything at this stage

Comment: @Kevin Ah, I see! There's nothing to tell Scala what's `T`, because the implicit conversion was not evaluated yet! Well, you could create an inner class to Collatable, and move the implicit there. That way, the type of T would have been inferred already. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @Daniel **[facepalm]** Of course it's not bound yet, that explains everything. Schoolboy error...

Comment: Well, either that or it's something deeply profound and we've just invented a new pattern. But my money's still on schoolboy error.